# Работа STDIN быстрее чем перебор и чтение файлов

Tags: perl, производительность

был скрипт который строки получал через STDIN

cat '...' | perl ...

работал очень быстро, но из-за определенных моментов пришлось переписать на перебор файлов перлом, открытие и чтение, стал на несколько порядков медленнее работать, почему так?

т.е. что я сделал, я перебираю файлы, открываю определенные, применяю регулярку

```
foreach($txt =~ /.../gsm) {
       ParsLine($_);
}
```

Вот на это все тратятся 15 минут.

Если закомментировать вызов ParsLine, код отрабатывает за 5 сек.
Если вызывать тот же ParsLine из цикла while (), тратится 33 сек. 
Почему же так долго выполняется программа?

Пробовал NYTProf, но так и не разобрался с ним (я с перлом только знакомлюсь), куда нужно подсунуть nytprof.out что бы посмотреть результаты.

Comment: С такой постановкой вопроса, без приведения конкретных команд и данных, лучше обращаться в клуб телепатии, во-вторых, что вы желаете добиться в итоге регуляркой _/.../gsm_, цель какая?

Comment: а в $txt хранится содержимое всего файла?

Comment: greg zakharov, ты интересный такой, может это известная история у перла, я ж не знаю

Comment: в $txt да, полный файл

Comment: @АртемАртемыч, тыкать будете знакомым, - постарайтесь соблюдать деловую этику. Во-вторых, вы так и не объяснили в чем суть вопроса? Если вы про скорость обработки данных поступающих Perl через stdin, нужен, повторюсь, конкретный пример, чтобы объяснить почему происходит то-то и то-то. Ну, а раз ничего этого нет, не обессутьте, ваш вопрос бессмысленный.

Comment: @greg zakharov, тебя никто не просит отвечать, если вопрос для тебя бессмысленный, пройди мимо. Нет, нужно что-то ляпнуть...

Comment: Вот, а теперь похоже и есть ответ. Когда обрабатывалось перенаправление с консоли, похоже что обработка шла построчно. А теперь Вы сами в коде дробите и обрабатываете. А это почти всегда сильно медленнее.

Comment: @KoVadim, а за счет чего замедление может происходить? Ведь сам цикл в котором дробление происходит (просто цикл без вызовов) быстро отрабатывает.

Comment: потому что когда Вы просто "только дробите", Вы почти ничего не делаете. Поэтому и быстро. Но в любом случае орудование небольшими строками по пару сот байт и орудование большими кусками в мегабайты имеет существенную разницу в скорости.

Comment: *куда нужно подсунуть nytprof.out* -- после получения `nytprof.out` его можно преобразовать в HTML: `/usr/local/bin/nytprofhtml --file nytprof.out` . Потом открывать `index.html` и смотреть, там всё наглядно (ну или [man nytprofhtml](http://manpages.org/nytprofhtml) для подробностей)